# Bootstrap Table Formatter for URL

Tags: javascript, html, json, formatter, bootstrap-table

Javascript:

```
function LinkFormatter(value, row, index) {
  return "<a href='"+row.url+"'>"+value+"</a>";
}
```

HTML:

```
<th data-field="snum" data-sortable="true" data-formatter="LinkFormatter" >LINK</th>
<th data-sortable="true">DATA</th>
```

JSON:

```
{
  data: [
    [
      "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
      "Stackoverflow"
    ]
  ]
}
```

For this combination I only get an entry in the first column in the table that sais undefined and also links to /undefined. I however just want one column that display Stackoverflow and is a URL to stackoverflow.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will have to change your JSON.

It should be something like this:

```
[ 
  {
    "url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "nice_name": "Stackoverflow"
  },
  {
    "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
    "nice_name": "Facebook"
  }
];
```

```js
var data = [{
  "url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "nice_name": "Stackoverflow"
}, {
  "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
  "nice_name": "Facebook"
}];

function linkFormatter(value, row) {
  return "<a href='" + row.url + "'>" + row.nice_name + "</a>";
}

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<table data-toggle="#table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="url" data-formatter="linkFormatter" data-sortable="true">Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

[Example on bootstrap-table site](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/#options/format.html) where same JSON format is required when initializing table through data fields. Example:

```
<table id="table"
       data-toggle="table"
       data-height="460"
       data-url="../json/data1.json">
  <thead>
```

[Bootstrap documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/) & [examples](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/)