# Show php data in data-formatter function of bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap-table

I have created a bootstrap-table in `table.php` file and define a table heading with data-formatter like this

`<th data-field='edit'  data-formatter="editFormatter">Edit</th>`

and i have create function for this,

```
function editFormatter(value, row)
{
   return `<a href="<?= URL::to('xyz/label'); ?>"  ><i class="fa fa-pencil sg-edit-btn" ></i></a>`
}
```

but when I inspect on `table.php` page it is showing anchor like this,

`<a href="<?= URL::to('xyz/label'); ?>`

why php code doesn't convert like this,

`<a href="https://localhost/app/public/xyz/label" class="btn sg-primary-btn">`

is there any way to do this? thanks in advance

Comment: I tried, but not working, the problem is PHP code is not running,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51176523/bootstrap-table-formatter-for-url - Hope this resolves your answer to the question :)

Comment: `row.url` is `undefined` in my case

Comment: Try My Answers Example with another file

Comment: Clientside vs. serverside? Is that function inside a .php file or inside a .js file (which will not get parsed by PHP)?

Comment: try <a href="<?php echo URL::to('xyz/label'); ?>

Comment: @kerbholz this function in `.js` file but it will return value in bootstrap-table which is in .php ` file

Comment: .php code in a .js file will not be parsed (unless you tell your server to handle .js files as .php files). JS is client side, PHP is run on the server.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [{
  "url": "https://www.stackoverflow.com",
  "nice_name": "Stackoverflow"
}, {
  "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
  "nice_name": "Facebook"
}];

function linkFormatter(value, row) {
  return "<a href='" + row.url + "'>" + row.nice_name + "</a>";
}

$(function() {
  $('#table').bootstrapTable({
    data: data
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.14.2/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">

<table data-toggle="#table" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th data-field="url" data-formatter="linkFormatter" data-sortable="true">Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```